# Page with ajax content does not remember a state after browser back button

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets, history.js

My webapp is pretty simple

servlet:

```
String greetings = "Hello from Servlet 1";
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(greetings);
```

jsp page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.history.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
    <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="push1()">pushState 1</button>
    <p>
        <a href="help.html">help.html</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

app-ajax.js:

```
function push1() {
    History.pushState({state:1,rand:Math.random()}, "State 1", "?state=1");
    $.get('servlet_1', {
    }, function(responseText) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
    });
}
```

When I click the button I recive `ajax` content in jsp but after I go to `help.html` page and go back by browser back button the jsp page does not remember the last page state (with ajax content). How can I make the jsp page remember last history state?

Answer (score 0):

Save the ajax content in localstorage or cookies then put a condition when page loaded .

Comment: Could you add more details to your answer how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Nattu Raju localStorage may help you see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) link to see how to implement this

you can try something like this

```js
var pageState
 = {};

function push1() {
    History.pushState({state:1,rand:Math.random()}, "State 1", "?state=1");
    $.get('servlet_1', {
    }, function(responseText) {
      var u ={}
      if(u == null){
      u.data = responseText;
        localStorage.setItem("pageState", u);
      }
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
      
    });
}

after that you may get your data just by calling localStorage.getItem("pageState");
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this dude

```
var pagestate = localStorage.getItem("pstate")

if(pagestate!=undefined || pagestate!=null){
   // so page having some state which is stored in localstorage
   // we have a pagestate in var pagestate
   // do changes based on pagestate variable
}
else
{
    // call server to fetch data and do other
    // save the pagestate as below
    localStorage.setItem("pstate", ajaxdata)
}
```

Comment: you can do this in cookies as well